# How do I setup phpmyadmin to connect to our DB which is hosted on Google Cloud?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, cloud

I have installed phpmyadmin but whenever I try to connect to the database, I get a "Can't connect to the MySql Server". When I try to add the ip address of my laptop to the list of allowed ip addresses within the Google Cloud configuration, it says it can't allow private ip addresses. Could that be the issue? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: you need to put in your PUBLIC ip, e.g. whatever IP your router/modem gets from your ISP.

Comment: try adding a new user with host `%` and see if you can connect with that.

Comment: Thanks very much for you answers!  I did try adding a new user with host % and I still wasn't successful.

Comment: Marc B - How do I find the PUBLIC ip address that I should add to the allowed connections within Google? My internet provider is Charter. I tried adding the various ip addresses I found when doing an "ipconfig" on my local laptop - but all of those gave me that "can't allow private ip address" message.  I looked at the "CIDR Notation" help link on the Google SQL Cloud  Allow Access page but that only confused me more.  Any help would MUCH appreciated.   Thanks - Lana

Comment: Oh - I just used whatismyipaddress.com and found it that way. Thanks. I think I am on the right track now. Thanks for the help!